# What does the "-E" mean at the end of a CBOE options symbol?

Tags: options

Below is are some option quotes taken directly from the CBOE website. I am wondering what the 
`-E, -4, -8, -A, -B, -I, -J etc..`that are at the end of the options symbol mean?

Example: `AAPL1513C109-E`

More examples:

`5 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109),13.48,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109),0.08,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-4),0.0,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-4),0.82,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-8),9.72,0.0, , ,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-8),0.83,0.0, , ,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-A),10.70,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-A),1.62,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-B),0.0,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-B),0.66,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-E),13.48,0.0,20.40,20.70,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-E),0.08,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-I),0.0,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-I),0.12,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-J),0.0,0.0,18.70,22.20,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-J),0.0,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-O),11.30,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-O),0.09,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-P),0.0,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-P),0.12,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-S),0.0,0.0, , ,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-S),0.0,0.0, , ,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-X),10.45,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-X),0.13,0.0,0.07,0.10,0,426,
15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513C109-Y),0.0,0.0,20.45,20.65,0,51,15 Mar 109.00 (AAPL1513O109-Y),0.0,0.0,0.0,5.00,0,426,=`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This letter (if present) indicates which exchange(s) the option trades at, whereby:
>       No hyphen or letter present = Composite
>       A = AMEX American Stock Exchange
>       B = BOX Boston Stock Exchange - Options
>       E = CBOE Chicago Board Options Exchange
>       I = BATS
>       J = NASDAQ OMX BX
>       O = NASDAQ OMX
>       P = NYSE Arca
>       X = PHLX Philadelphia Stock Exchange
>       Y = C2 Exchange
>       4 = Miami Options Exchange
>       8 = ISE International Securities Exchange

Source: http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quotehelp.aspx#chaindata

Comment: This was hugely helpful.  What is a 'Composite' price?

Comment: There is actually 3 more - 3, K, OG, S - anybody has an idea where to find a description to them?